# Sort a special ordered array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

**Background:**

The app I was working on has a large menu. However, they are not sorted. That was built by a previous developer. Now I am asked to make the menu in the correct order.

The menu has many items. Each items has sub-menus. Sub-menus can also have their own sub-menus.
The following is an example.

[image]

Based on the existing program, the following array of items were given. (The menu is created based on this array.)

**[A, D, E, B, C, F, H, G]**

You can see that parent node is followed by its children nodes, then followed by siblings.

**My thoughts:**

I have 2 approaches. One is to change the existing program so it will output the array in the correct orders at the first place. Second is to sort the array that is generated by the existing program. In order not to mess up the existing functionality. I prefer the second way, which is to change the order of the generated array.

**My Questions:**

Therefore, I want to sort the array so that it looks like

**[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]**

So that the final menu would look like the following:

[image]

Any codes provided will be really appreciated. I am using Java, but any other language or pseudocode would be welcome as well.

**Updates:**

I am sorry that I did not make it clearer. I was trying to keep the question simple so that you do not need to know too much useless and distracting information. Somehow I missed some important info that you may need to know.

Here is some more info that I need you need to know.

**The item in an array is an Object. The object has the a menu level, and parent id.**

For example,

- Menu A's level is 0, it has no parent.
- Menu D's parent is Menu A, the level is 1.
- Menu C's parent is menu B. Menu C's level is 2

I hope this update will help you understand my question more.

Comment: do you already have any code?

Comment: Is there a way to tell, say, B is a sub-menu of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a tree like structure you can leverage that with a custom comparison function and do something like this:

(Python-like pseudocode)

```
'''
Assuming Menu is defined or can be transformed to be as follows:
class Menu():
    #submenus is a list of menus under a menu
    def __init__(submenus):
        self.submenus = submenus
        # other menu members
'''
# menus is a list of top level menu items.
# cmp is the comparison fxn for two menus
def sort_menus(menus,cmp)
    all_sorted_menus = []
    sort_menus_helper(menus,cmp,all_sorted_menus)
    return all_sorted_menus

def sort_menus_helper(menus,cmp,all_sorted_menus=None):
    if all_sorted_menus is None:
       all_sorted_menus = []
    sorted_menus = menus.sort(cmp=cmp)
    for menu in menus:
        sorted_menus.append(menu)
        sort_menus(menu.submenus,cmp,all_sorted_menus)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Your codes are actually very similar to what I did. I was actually looking for a another way to sort on array instead of reconstruct an array of trees. However, I know the method you provided works. I will flag your reply as answer because you are really smart that you can write a solution to my question without knowing enough info. You know about assuming some condition  based on the limited info. Your talent deserved to have rewards.